# Postgres 13.8 - How to return all rows while performing window operations on data

Tags: postgresql

Please suggest how to implement the below requirement in Postgres 13.8, while returning all the rows of the original data:

```
CREATE TABLE exam_assessment (
    subject_name varchar(50),
    chapter_name varchar(50),
    chapter_status varchar(50),
    student_id varchar(50),
    marked_status varchar(50));

INSERT INTO exam_assessment 
(subject_name,chapter_name,chapter_status,student_id,marked_status) VALUES
('Science','Chapter1','COMPLETED','6998104_1','Marked as Complete'),
('Science','Chapter2','COMPLETED','6998104_1','Completed'),
('Science','Chapter3','IN_PROGRESS','6998104_1','IN_PROGRESS'),
('Science','Chapter1','COMPLETED','6998103_1','Marked as Complete'),
('Science','Chapter2','COMPLETED','6998103_1','Marked as Complete'),
('Science','Chapter3','COMPLETED','6998103_1','Marked as Complete'),
('Science','Chapter1','COMPLETED','6998102_1','Completed'),
('Science','Chapter2','COMPLETED','6998102_1','Marked as Complete'),
('Science','Chapter3','COMPLETED','6998102_1','Marked as Complete');
```

**Data** looks like This:

| subject_name | chapter_name | chapter_status | student_id | marked_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998104_1 | Marked as Complete |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998104_1 | Completed |
| Science | Chapter3 | IN_PROGRESS | 6998104_1 | IN_PROGRESS |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete |
| Science | Chapter3 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Completed |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Marked as Complete |
| Science | Chapter3 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Marked as Complete |

The **objective** is to get the Overall subject status for a student:

- If any chapter is `IN_PROGRESS`, it means that the subject status is `IN PROGRESS`.
- If all the chapters are `Marked as Completed`, the subject status should be `Marked as Completed`.
- If all the chapters are a combination of `Marked as Completed` and `Completed`, it means that the subject status should be `Completed`.

**Examples:**

- Student `6998104_1` has some `marked_status` of the 3 chapters as `IN_PROGRESS` - `SUBJECT_STATUS` should show `IN_PROGRESS`.
- Student `6998103_1` has `marked_status` in all chapters as `Marked as Complete` - `SUBJECT_STATUS` should show `Marked as Complete`.
- Student `6998102_1` has ALL `chapter_status` of the 3 chapters as `COMPLETED`, BUT some of them have `marked_status` as `Marked as Complete` and some have `Completed` - `SUBJECT_STATUS` column should show `Completed`.

**Expected result:**

| subject_name | chapter_name | chapter_status | student_id | marked_status | **SUBJECT_STATUS** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998104_1 | Marked as Complete | **IN_PROGRESS** |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998104_1 | Completed | **IN_PROGRESS** |
| Science | Chapter3 | IN_PROGRESS | 6998104_1 | IN_PROGRESS | **IN_PROGRESS** |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete | **Marked as Complete** |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete | **Marked as Complete** |
| Science | Chapter3 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete | **Marked as Complete** |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Completed | **Completed** |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Marked as Complete | **Completed** |
| Science | Chapter3 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Marked as Complete | **Completed** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list your rules in a `case`, where you use [`every()`/`bool_and()` and `bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) over a [window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) that limits them to each student's subject chapters: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/yLdUed0X)

```sql
select *, case when bool_or(chapter_status='IN_PROGRESS')over w1
               then 'IN_PROGRESS'
               when every(chapter_status='COMPLETED')over w1 and
                    every(marked_status='Marked as Complete')over w1
               then 'Marked as Complete'
               when every(chapter_status='COMPLETED')over w1 and
                    bool_or(marked_status='Completed')over w1
               then 'Completed' 
          end as "SUBJECT_STATUS"
from exam_assessment
window w1 as (partition by subject_name,student_id)
order by student_id desc, chapter_name asc;
```

| subject_name | chapter_name | chapter_status | student_id | marked_status | SUBJECT_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998104_1 | Marked as Complete | IN_PROGRESS |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998104_1 | Completed | IN_PROGRESS |
| Science | Chapter3 | IN_PROGRESS | 6998104_1 | IN_PROGRESS | IN_PROGRESS |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete | Marked as Complete |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete | Marked as Complete |
| Science | Chapter3 | COMPLETED | 6998103_1 | Marked as Complete | Marked as Complete |
| Science | Chapter1 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Completed | Completed |
| Science | Chapter2 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Marked as Complete | Completed |
| Science | Chapter3 | COMPLETED | 6998102_1 | Marked as Complete | Completed |

Comment: Does the job perfectly, thanks @zegarek !